# Right button mouse not working on Mozilla Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I am developing an extension for Firefox. The problem is that I can't see Inspect Element for an extension, extension screen just doesn't respond to right mouse click. I can select dropdown, can select, can edit, but can't invoke Inspect Element.

How can I do that? Sorry if the question is duplicated, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume you are talking panel here. I find it more convenient to open it in a proper tab with a chrome:// URL. Try messing around with the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) if that fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger.